# How to pass array environment variables to heroku using figaro gem

Tags: heroku, environment-variables, figaro-ruby

My `application.yml` file is as follows:

```
KEYS: ["xxxxxx", "yyyyyy", "zzzzzz"]
```

When I run `figaro heroku:set`

I receive this error:

```
.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/figaro-1.1.1/lib/figaro/cli/heroku_set.rb:7:in `system': no implicit conversion of Integer into String (TypeError)
```

Anyone know how I should format arrays in `application.yml`?

Answer (score 5):

Heroku only allows plain strings as environmental variables. If you still want to pass an array, you need to join it into string and then split in your code.

```
# application.yml
KEYS: "xxxxxx,yyyyyy,zzzzzz"
```

And then in your application code you can use it like

```
(ENV["KEYS"] || "").split(",")
```